# Android - set size text item

Tags: android

I have a menu.xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".StudentMarks" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_example"
        android:title="@string/action_example"
        android:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        style="@style/SelectedYear" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

The item action example has a title that represents the current year (2014).
I can see it in the action bar but i don't know how can I set the size of the year. 
I would like to make it bigger.

my styles.xml files

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="SelectedYear" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this attribute in xml

```
   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
```

Comment: doesnt change anything

Comment: it should change.. normally these are the options we use to change the text size.. in fact I used the same and got result

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: this i did before and it works, but i would like to create a new style so i can split better the things. so id added a new tag in the style.xml file but in this way doesnt change anything

Comment: Can you post your styles.xml?

Comment: look my first post, i attached my styles.xml file.